# App indicator icons too small after update to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome-shell, indicator, 20.04

After updating to Ubuntu 20.04, app indicators became very small, and now when an app like Telegram has notifications, they are just overlapping the whole icon. Is there a way to adjust this manually?

### Screenshot 1 - Smaller icon:

Notice how the Telegram icon (blue circle with white paper flyer) is smaller than the two icons next to it (Slack on the right).

[image: Telegram when it doesn't have a notification]

#### Screenshot 2 - Clipped and deformed:

Notice the Telegram icon (grey circle with the nubmer "2" in it).  Firstly it's clipped; the top and left side of he circle are not shown.  Secondly, the grey circle is in fact a badge that is supposed to be placed so it only partially covers the normal blue Telegram icon (similar to the inbox icon shown in the browser on the screenshot); instead it's scaled to take up all the space:

[image: Telegram when it has notification]

Comment: From the screenshot, it's doesn't look very inconsistent with the other items in the top bar to me.

Comment: I don't see the problem either. Please take the screenshot and put a circle around the area of concern.

Comment: The digit is actually the Telegram icon. The icons are surely much smaller than they were in 19.10, but I can live with that, even though they look blurry. I edited the initial post to show the issue. You can see that it's also cut from a side.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the screenshot, but I've added some clarifying descriptions on what to look for exactly.

Comment: Since Telegram is the only app I'm seeing this issue with, I've reported the issue to the Telegram support though their web site and linked to this post.  I don't know if this is the correct approach, but .. it's definitely _an_ approach.

Comment: Thanks, Stephan, as it was working well in the previous release I thought it's a Ubuntu/Gnome issue. But apparently Telegram just doesn't support some new indicators setting I guess. Thanks for reporting it.

Comment: I have this problem too. after upgrading to 20.04 my indicator icons are smaller than 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to modify the size of the status bar indicators (or other settings such as padding), you can do so with the Just Perfection extension (https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3843/just-perfection/).
(Note that you cannot do this on an app-by-app basis. However, you might take a look at the settings to see if there is anything helpful in there.